# Join sin que los campos de las dos tablas coincidan LinQ

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Soy nuevo en Linq y querría saber como puedo obtener todas las parejas de nombre de marcas y nombre de clientes que no sean de la misma ciudad. Ambas tablas tienen el campo ciudad.

```
var consulta = sqldam220Concesionarios.Marcas
                        .Join(sqldam220Concesionarios.Clientes,
                                m => m.ciudad,
                                c => c.ciudad,
                                (m, c) => new
                                {
                                    nombreMarca = m.nombre,
                                    nombreCliente = c.nombre,
                                    ciudadMarca = m.ciudad,
                                    ciudadCliente = m.ciudad,
                                })
                        .OrderBy(j => j.nombreMarca)
                        .Select(j => new
                        {
                            j.nombreMarca,
                            j.nombreCliente
                        });
```

Si necesitan cualquier aclaración, avisen. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de tus datos de entrada y los datos de salida que esperas recibir?

Comment: Perdona pero, ¿A que te refieres exactamente? Los datos que quiero que muestren son el nombre de las marcas y el nombre de los diferentes clientes. @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: Me refiero a que compartas un ejemplo de tu conjunto de datos y un ejemplo de qué quieres recibir tras procesar dicho conjunto de datos.

Comment: Yo tengo una tabla en SQL llamada Marcas que contiene su primary key , el nombre de la marca y su ciudad y tengo otra tabla en SQL llamada Clientes que tiene su primary key, el nombre y la ciudad del cliente. 

Quiero conseguir una consulta que muestre todas las parejas de nombre de marcas y nombre de clientes que no sean de la misma ciudad, es decir, en el join poner la condición de que sean distintas las ciudades de la marca y del cliente. @PaperBirdMaster

Comment: Me parece bien que describas lo que tienes, pero me parecería aún mejor que **mostrases** un ejemplo de lo que tienes. Si insisto tanto es porque no entiendo ni lo que tienes ni lo que quieres conseguir. Ayúdame a ayudarte.

Answer (score 0):

Para conocer los items que tienes en una lista y no se relacionan con la otra se utiliza el `left join` puedes hacerlo con `linq`

[Realizar operaciones de combinación externa izquierda](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins)

entonces seria

```
var consulta = from m in sqldam220Concesionarios.Marcas
                join c in sqldam220Concesionarios.Clientes on m.ciudad equals c.ciudad into gj
                from mc in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where mc == null
                select m;
```

lo realiza en notacion linq porque se entiende mucho mejor

La idea es que al usar el `into` puedes evaluar si la relacion no existe y devolver los marcas que no tienen cliente